# How do I force the new settings to work in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I changed the settings in Unity, in the Project Settings - Qualify window. But when I start the game, a warning "Changes made in play mode will not be saved" appears in the Qualify section. How to make the settings work?
[Project Settings - Qualify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKNnu.png)

I restarted Unity, but everything is still the same. The warning still appears, the new settings do not take effect.

Comment: No it says in playmode.. Just dont be in playmode.. edit stuff then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message is meant to warn you that if you change settings while in Play Mode, those changes will not be saved.
This is handy if you want to test settings without worrying about messing your previous configuration.
If you made changes to your Quality config outside Play Mode, those should be applied and saved.

Comment: I already understand. The problem was different. And I thought that the problem was in the message.